# How to make explode(....)[1] work on PHP < 5.4?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this line in my code.

```
$result = explode(":",$splitted[$i])[1]; // (PHP 5.4 syntax)
```

It generates a fatal error on not supported versions, can someone tell me how to make this code backward compatible?

Thanks

Comment: $result = explode(":",$splitted[$i]); $result = $result[1];

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in two statements.

```
<?php
$arr = explode(":",$splitted[$i]);
$result = $arr[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or by using one statement using the [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) construct:

```
list(, $result) = explode(":", $splitted[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(,$result) = explode(":",'1:2:3:4');
print_r($result); // 2
```